# Web scraping tables using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to extract a table from Wikipedia list of noble laureates .The table has some none value I don't know how to take care of those values.while looping through the cells How can I include the none values in the table. The link to the Wikipedia page is :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
r=requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable')

rows = table.find_all('tr')
del rows[0]


for row in rows:
    cells=row.find_all('td')
    records=[]
    print(cells)


    year = cells[0].text
    print("contents",cells[1].contents[1].text)
    physics_winner = cells[1].contents[1].text
    physics_url = cells[1].find('a')['href']
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: My output should be in a csv file with the names all the noble laureates , their discipline , their respective URL and year in which they received the award

Comment: Did you try `wikitablescrape`, It's a python package

Comment: No I haven't tried it. Could you please help me through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try and except just as long as you know what exception will be thrown for the None in the table. I'm not sure of your desired output but I do see you are importing pandas so look into the [replace function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for a better alternative to the try/excepts

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd

    r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable')

    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    del rows[0]


    for row in rows[:20]:
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        records = []

        try:
            year = cells[0].text
        except IndexError:
            year = 'n/a'

        try: 
            print("contents", cells[1].contents[1].text)
        except IndexError:
            print("contents", 'n/a')

        try: 
            physics_winner = cells[1].contents[1].text
        except IndexError:
            physics_winner = 'n/a'

        try:
            physics_url = cells[1].find('a')['href'] 
        except TypeError:
            physics_url = 'n/a'
```

Comment: Thanks for you response but I am still getting an error  :
year = cells[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: add 
        `try: 
           year = cells[0].text
        except IndexError:
           year = 'n/a'`

Comment: I tried it and it worked . URL is also giving me an index error . Is there any way to add an exception for both TypeError and IndexError?

Comment: ok you can just leave the exception as blank per say to handle anything but I highly advise against this cause you can have errors occur and not know

try catch all
`
try:
    something
except:
      do some thing no matter what happens`

Comment: here is a great [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/handling-exceptions-try-except-python-3/) on try/except

Comment: I figured out the solution for this problem . Could you please tell me how to extract multiple names from the table? In a single year more than one people have won the noble prize . I am only able to retrieve one name out of it. I want to retrieve all the names. Thanks

Comment: I gotta go but I'll send you down the right path, your indexing the first cell in each row that's why your getting only the first name you need to iterate through the cells in each row as you iterate through the rows



        `for row in rows:
            cells = row.find_all('td')
            for i in cells:
                print(i.text)`

Answer (score 0):

for the iteration through the cells

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd

    r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable')

    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    del rows[0]


    for row in rows[:15]:
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        for cell in cells:
            print(cell.text)
            # print(cells)
            # records = []


            try:
                year = cell.text
            except IndexError:
                year = 'n/a'

            try: 
                print("contents", cell.contents[1].text)
            except IndexError:
                print("contents", 'n/a')

            try: 
                physics_winner = cell.contents[1].text
            except IndexError:
                physics_winner = 'n/a'

            try:
                physics_url = cell.find('a')['href'] 
            except TypeError:
                physics_url = 'n/a'
```